# Query by more than one parameters

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jakarta-ee

am doing an online credit top up application .
and i want to get the voucher from database by its category,type and denomination.
I need help on the query i have insert in the creatquery()  and setparameter() methods.
 this is my code snippet for to get the voucher.

```
public String getVoucherPinByCategoryTypeDeno(String category, String type, double denomination) {
        return (String) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from voucher v where v.category = :category and v.voucherType = :type and v.denomination = :denomination").setparameter().uniqueResult();
    }
```

Comment: i guess voucher is not a String

Comment: @AlmoullimDev. php? this is java xD

Comment: @nachokk oh !!, then i must be losing my mind `sorry` :L

Answer (score 2):

You need a query something like this

```
Voucher voucher = (Voucher) session.createQuery("from Voucher v where v.category = :category and v.voucherType = :type and v.denomination = :denomination")
.setString("category", category)
.setString("voucherType", type)
.setDouble("denomination", denomination)
.uniqueResult();
```